# Why does the closure take ownership of the vector here?

Tags: rust

The rust documentation has this example in the [Closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html) section.

```
let nums = vec![1, 2, 3];

let takes_nums = || nums;

println!("{:?}", nums);
```

The documentation says

> If your closure requires it, however, Rust will take ownership and
>   move the environment instead

And the above code results in this error

```
note: `nums` moved into closure environment here because it has type
  `[closure(()) -> collections::vec::Vec<i32>]`, which is non-copyable
let takes_nums = || nums;
                 ^~~~~~~
```

for which the docs say

> Vec has ownership over its contents, and therefore, when we refer
>   to it in our closure, we have to take ownership of nums. It’s the same
>   as if we’d passed nums to a function that took ownership of it.

I don't understand why the closure doesn't just borrow the ownership of the vector as it does in this example from the documentation

```
let num = 5;
let plus_num = |x: i32| x + num;

assert_eq!(10, plus_num(5));
```

> This closure, plus_num, refers to a let binding in its scope: num.
>   More specifically, it borrows the binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer lies in the signature of the closure: what does `takes_num` return?

It returns `nums`, whose type is `Vec<i32>`.

To give ownership of something to someone, you must first own it, otherwise it's not yours to give. The same rule applies to the closure.